# Show/Hide Panel Form1 in Usercontrol

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

Anyone know how can I hide/show panel of `Form1` but my button is in `UserControl`, I want to add button in `UserControl` to hide and show panel of `Form1`. How can i do that?

Here's my code for hide and show:

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    flag *= -1;
    if (flag == 1)
        bunifuGradientPanel1.Hide();
    else
        bunifuGradientPanel1.Show();
}
```

Comment: The correct option is for your user control to raise an event that the form can handle and then it can hide its own `Panel`. See [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html) for information on raising your own events. I'll add an answer when I get a chance, if no one else beats me to it.

Answer (score 1):

Controls should not know about their containers explicitly, in order to maintain loose coupling. Any control can call its `FindForm` method to get a reference to its form of type `Form`. That should only be used to do general form things though. A child control should not know that its parent form is a specific type, never mind what that type contains.

The proper way to do this is for the user control to raise an event. That event can notify any listeners that something has happened and those listeners can then do whatever is required. In this case, the form would handle the event of the user control and then hide its own `Panel`.

The user control might contain code like this:

```cs
public event EventHandler Button1Click;

protected void OnButton1Click(EventArgs e)
{
    Button1Click?.Invoke(this, e);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnButton1Click(EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

For more information on raising your own events, see [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html).

When the user clicks `button1` on the user control, that user control will raise its `Button1Click` event. The form containing the user control can then handle that event and do whatever is required, just as it could handle the `Click` event of a regular `Button` and do whatever is required, e.g.

```cs
private void someUserControl1_Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Visible = !panel1.Visible;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but not working. when i click button in the usercontrol panel is not hiding nothing change.